# Problem with huge numbers in an incremental game (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

i am currently working on an idle/incremental game and have found myself in a situation where i am getting a problem with my incrementing variables like for example the cost of game objects or the high score e.g. I am multiplying by two of the cost of my game objects so that at some point in the game it outputs a negative cost value because the data type reached max value. I want to make the score somehow infinite not just the maximal value of the current data type. 
My idea was to show the score with a suffix like "k" "m" etc. and after "t" for trillions to make it "a" -"z" then "aa" and so on("50a1T", "66aa2z"). I tried to make a `Dictionary<Numbers, int> number;` whereas Numbers present an enum of my suffixes and int the value e.g. how much thousands or millions i have. At the end i would've return all values into a string like for example 10,2 M.

---

I feel like theres a much better solution ^^

Comment: Python and C# are quite different languages.

Comment: Have you looked at the decimal and/or long data types? They can hold really big numbers.

Comment: And if you still need something bigger than `long`, there is always `BigInteger`.